# Observer doesn't detect array push

Tags: javascript, ractivejs

as I've been discovering this library more and more, I'm stuck at this one single thing.

I have this **staticData** array:

```
staticData = {
    buildingsQueue : [
        { current: false, building : 14, queueID : 1, elapsed : 27, finish : 46 },
        { current: false, building : 4, queueID : 2, elapsed : 0, finish : 25 }
    ]
}
```

And this Ractive instance:

```
var townController = {
    init : function () {
        townTPL = new Ractive({
            el : 'pageContainer',
            append : true,
            template : templates.town,
            data : {
                staticUrl : staticData.url,
                queue : staticData.village.buildingsQueue
            }
        });

        townTPL.observe('queue.*',function(newValue,oldValue,keypath){
            console.log('changed::'+keypath);
        });

    }
```

My buildingsQueue will get processed one at a time, and the townController will set the **current** key to true so I decided to make an observer for **queue.*** following **[Rich's example](http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/observers)**

```
var ractive = new Ractive({
  el: myContainer,
  template: myTemplate,
  data: {
    people: [
      {name: 'Rich Harris'},
      {name: 'Marty Nelson'}
    ]
  }
});

ractive.observe('people.*', function(newValue, oldValue, keypath) {

});

var people = ractive.get('people');
people.push({name: 'Jason Brown'});
//newValue will equal 3, and the keypath will be people.length
```

The problem is that **buildingQueue** changes over time, and pushing data like the following doesn't fire the observer callback:

```
var list = TownTPL.get('queue');
list.push({ current: true, building : 1, queueID : 4, elapsed : 0, finish : 36 })
// OR   
staticData.buildingsQueue.push({ current: true, building : 1, queueID : 4, elapsed : 0, finish : 36 });
```

The observer doesn't fire as Rich's documentation says it should in it's example. My logic is that observers only work with the array items that are in the array when initiated, but I'm pretty sure that's not true and it should work with dynamic arrays, so, please enlighten me on this one.

**TO BE AWARE OF**
I'm firing the push events from outside the **init** function , Javascript Console for example, or another javascript object.

**FIXED PROLEM**
I've updated the plugin to the edge version, still 0.4.0 like the one I was using, but, this one was released two days ago. Thanks Rich and Marty, whatever you did in those commits.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Dz4RZ/ seems to be working (edge version). Let's figure out what is different from your use. Also, what version are you using?

Comment: @martypdx http://jsfiddle.net/Dz4RZ/1/ , I'm using 0.4.0 , seems like using an sub-array doesn't work. Or am I doing something wrong there.

Comment: You used the wrong variable, should be `staticData.log`. http://jsfiddle.net/Dz4RZ/3/ . Maybe that's the issue that `observe` swallows errors? Try adding `console.log` to see if it's firing.

Comment: Ah wait, in `4.0` observing arrays worked a bit different, with only a `length` keypath on add. See http://jsfiddle.net/Dz4RZ/4/. It still fires, but only for the length change, not with the items themselves (which if I remember correctly was possibly a bug). We dropped length as being a match for `queue.*` for 4.1 but still explicitly observable via `queue.length`.

Comment: I updated the edge version , apparenly my versin was released a week ago or something like that and this version of 4.0 was released 2 days ago. I didn't change anything in my code but works with the edge version so. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by updating to the edge version.